# How to find the final target of a daisy-chain of symbolic links?

Tags: symbolic-link

I needed to issue several commands to follow a chain of symbolic links to the final target.

Is there a command which will do it in a single step?

```
which updatedb
/usr/bin/updatedb  

ls -l /usr/bin/updatedb  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2010-09-01 16:22 /usr/bin/updatedb -> /etc/alternatives/updatedb  

ls -l /etc/alternatives/updatedb  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 2010-09-01 16:21 /etc/alternatives/updatedb -> /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate  

ls -l /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34492 2010-03-24 21:16 /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `readlink -e <linkfile>`. See readlink's [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/readlink.1.html) for more info on its arguments.

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely.... and I've just now found another one called `chase` which has a few extra options, eg. output the list of links it follows. ("chase" is in the Ubuntu repository)...

Comment: Keep in mind that this is the GNU version of `readlink`. Perfectly fine on Ubuntu, but you may get bitten when you attempt similar stunts on other unixoid systems. Just saying. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readlink -e`, as mentioned in @htorque, which is installed by default. However if you have done something like `ln -s a a` then `readlink -e a` will give no output at all, which is the same as when you do `readlink b` when `b` is a normal file.

If you install the package `chase` (`sudo apt-get install chase`, named for "chasing symlinks") you get much more informative output.

```
$ chase a
chase: /tmp/a: symlink loop detected, giving up...
$ chase b
/tmp/b
```

and you can run it verbose:

```
$ chase --verbose /opt/python/3
/opt/python/3
-> 3.6
-> 3.6.2
/opt/python/3.6.2
```

which shows the intermediate links